# Powershell menu script interativo. Não consigo sair(invalid option)

Tags: menu, powershell, submenu

Sou iniciante em *Powershell* e eu tenho um pequeno problema.

Eu tenho 2 *scripts* (menu e submenu). Eu executo script_A (menu) e quando seleciono a opção 9 (exit) funciona como esperado. Mas, quando eu executo o script_A e escolho a opção 1 (submenu), e depois escolho a opção 9(retornar para o script_A) e novamente seleciono 9 (exit), aparece essa mensagem: *invalid option.*

Porque? Alguém pode me ajudar? os scripts A e B são:

## Script_A:

```
$resposta = $null
$vocetemcerteza = $null

$PSScriptRoot
$ScriptToRun1= $PSScriptRoot+"\DNSMenu.ps1"

function vocetemcerteza {
      $vocetemcerteza = read-host "Do you have exit? (y/n)"  
         if ($vocetemcerteza -eq "y"){Exit}  
         elseif ($vocetemcerteza -eq "n"){mainmenu}  
         else {write-host -foregroundcolor red "Invalid Option."
            vocetemcerteza  
           }  
       }  


function mainmenu{  
$vocetemcerteza = "n"
cls
echo "    1. DNS"  
echo ""  
echo "    9. Exit" 

$resposta = read-host "Choose a option:"  
if ($resposta -eq 1){&$ScriptToRun1}  
if ($resposta -eq 9){vocetemcerteza} 
else {echo ""
   write-host -ForegroundColor magenta "Invalid Option."  
   sleep 1
   cls  
   mainmenu
   }  
   }  
 mainmenu
```

## Script_B:

```
$ScriptToRun1= $PSScriptRoot+"\DNSemLoteMenu.ps1"

function mainmenu{  
$vocetemcerteza = "n"
cls
echo "" 
echo "    1. Create register" 
echo ""  

$resposta = read-host "Choose a option:"  
   if ($resposta -eq 1){&$ScriptToRun1}  
   if ($resposta -eq 9){mainmenu} 
   else {echo ""
      write-host -ForegroundColor magenta "Invalid Option."  
      sleep 1
      mainmenu  
      }  
    }  
 mainmenu
```

Comment: Só uma dica, o teu menu devia estar dentro de um `Switch`, verifica o exemplo do link.... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730937.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Era um pequeno problema na linha 7 do Script_A.

Na função, na 3a linha: qdo desejamos sair de uma função o comando correto é "break". Como eu estava usando o "exit", dava a mensagem de erro.

Tirei a dúvida em outro post daqui mesmo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022326/terminating-a-script-in-powershell

Problema resolvido.